# How do I disable the effective 'time limit' on editing Kubernetes deployments?

Tags: kubernetes

If I edit a Kubernetes deployment (e.g. `kubectl edit deployment <name>` or using the Web UI), and wait too long before saving my changes and exiting, the deployment file will have changed while I was editing, resulting in an error notifying me that the file has changed (due to the status fields being updated since I began editing).

I know I *should* be using declarative state for this, but with my current setup (editing from CLI directly), is there some way to ignore these status changes when editing? It's a pain in the ass to have to rush to edit as quickly as I can before something changes state.